# MSVC2019 Build From CMD line: VCVARS32.BAT: "\Common was unexpected at this time."

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build an app from the CMD line using MSVC 2019.
The instructions that came with the project (libssl) say to run "VCVARS32.BAT" and then "nmake".
When I run VCVARS32.BAT, the following error message is emitted:

```
\Common was unexpected at this time
```

A similar issue was discussed in SO (#8756828) but that one applied to *modifying* VCVARS32 which I am not doing. An answer to that also mentioned quote marks within the PATH, but I checked and that is not so.

I am running from a base CMD.EXE prompt on a Dell Win10-64 machine.

**Any idea why this is happening?**

Comment: `set "VSCMD_DEBUG=3"` before running `vcvars32.bat` and it will `echo` the commands as it executes them, so you can see where the error comes from.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. The problem was quotes ("") in the PATH as suggested in answer to SO #8756828. Strangely, there were NO quotes in ControlPanel->System->Advanced->EnvironmentVariables->SystemVariables->PATH or in the Registry, however "echo %PATH%" *did* show quotes. By trial and error, I discovered that the offending component in my PATH was

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

When I removed that, all was good. At first, I suspected that the embedded spaces were the culprit, but then I noticed other PATH components with embedded spaces that caused no problems. So, I still don't understand what was going on but at least I have a working fix.